# Server 11.10 to be used as a DHCP server

Tags: dhcp

I am trying out an ubuntu server in my home network and I am planning to use it as a dhcp server.

Since ubuntu is installed in a desktop with just 1 Ethernet port my question:

1. Is it possible to configure both static public IP on the ethernet port at the same time that it is being used as a listening port for DHCP to distribute IP addresses on my network?
2. If it is, will it have any negative effect on the connection speed?

Answer (score 1):

The answers to your querstions:

1. It is possible to have two ip addresses on the same interface, and
   use `dhcp-server` with it. You will have to install the DHCP server using the command: `sudo apt-get install dhcp3-server` then configure using the steps given here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/dhcp3-server.
2. It will have no practical impact on your internet speed, as you're on a small home network.

Also note that you will have to set the routes and ip addresses for your ethernet interface using the network manager, or using the `ip` command. Hope this solves your query.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

What you're looking for is [sub-interfaces](http://www.wantlinux.net/2009/04/ubuntu-subinterfaces/).  Depending on the networking equipment you're using, it's also possible to do this with [vlans](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1744682.html).